# Pivoting a table with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, transpose

I have a table with position (junior, senior), salary, and an ID. I have done the following to find the highest salary for each position.

`SELECT position, MAX(salary) FROM candidates GROUP BY position;`

What I am getting:
[image]

How I want it:
[image]

I want to transpose the outcome so that 'junior' and 'senior' are the columns without using crosstab. I have looked at many pivot examples but they are done on examples much more complex than mine.

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not proficient in PostgreSQL, but I believe there is a practical workaround solution since this is a simple table:

```
SELECT 
    max(case when position = 'senior' then salary else null end) senior,
    max(case when position = 'junior' then salary else null end) junior
FROM payments
```

It worked with this example:

```
create table payments (id integer, position varchar(100), salary int);
        insert into payments (id, position, salary) values (1, 'junior', 1000);
        insert into payments (id, position, salary) values (1, 'junior', 2000);
        insert into payments (id, position, salary) values (1, 'junior', 5000);
        insert into payments (id, position, salary) values (1, 'junior', 3000);
        insert into payments (id, position, salary) values (2, 'senior', 3000);
        insert into payments (id, position, salary) values (2, 'senior', 8000);
        insert into payments (id, position, salary) values (2, 'senior', 9000);
        insert into payments (id, position, salary) values (2, 'senior', 7000);
        insert into payments (id, position, salary) values (2, 'senior', 4000);
        select 
            max(case when position = 'junior' then salary else 0 end) junior,
            max(case when position = 'senior' then salary else 0 end) senior
        from payments;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt at teaching myself crosstab:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

select Junior
  , Senior
from
(
  select *
  from crosstab
  (
    'select 1, position, max(salary)
    from candidates
    group by position
    '
    , $$VALUES('Junior'), ('Senior')$$
  )
  as ct(row_number integer, Junior integer, Senior integer) --I don't know your actual data types, so you will need to update this as needed
) q
```

### Edit: Below is no longer relevant as this appears to be PostgreSQL

Based on your description, it sounds like you probably want a pivot like this:

```
select q.*
from
(
    select position
        , salary
    from candidates
) q
pivot (
    max(salary) for position in ([Junior], [Senior])
) p
```

This example was made in SQL Server since we don't know DBMS.

Comment: gave me:     
ERROR: syntax error at or near "pivot" Position: 80

Comment: I am doing it on SQL Fiddle and not sure where I can activate the crosstab function. How would it look with crosstab?

Comment: thank you for your contribution. It looks right, but the row is empty (has 'null')

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which SQL dialect you are running. It also depends on the complexity of your table. In SQL Server, I believe you can use the solutions provided in this question for relatively simple tables: [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6  and the table is very simple